# Python - Access denied error on windows 8

Tags: python

I want to create a shortcut link to my app in "Programs/StartMenu" folder. so I used this codes:

```
def create_shortcuts():
    import pythoncom
    from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
    shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance (
      shell.CLSID_ShellLink,
      None,
      pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
      shell.IID_IShellLink
    )

    shortcut.SetPath ("path_to_my_app")
    shortcut.SetDescription ("Description")
    shortcut.SetIconLocation ("path_to_my_app_icon", 0)

    prg_path =  shell.SHGetFolderPath (0, shellcon.CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS, 0, 0)
    persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface (pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
    os.makedirs(prg_path + "\\myFolder")

    persist_file.Save(os.path.join (prg_path + "\\myFolder", "myApp.lnk"), 0)

create_shortcuts()
```

The problem is when I run this codes I face with Access denied error because `os.makedirs` does not have permission to create a folder in 'Programs' folder. This code is a part of installer setup and the users should run it without "Run as administrator".

OS: Windows 8
Python: 2.7

Comment: And even as Administrator it still yields the error?

Comment: @PauloBu No, It works as admin

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers - I'm not sure where you've picked the above code up from - nor the great picture of how you're trying to do this...

Comment: @JonClements - I wrote this code by searching msdn. I am coding an installer setup for a UDK software which my installer should install that software into a custom folder.

Comment: The answer was found. The program should be elevated by py2exe argument: `setup(console=[{'script':"process.py",'uac_info': "requireAdministrator"}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program should be elevated (using py2exe):

```
setup(console=[{'script':"process.py",'uac_info': "requireAdministrator"}])
```